# Collecting values of multiple checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

For convenience I'm giving the script and the html in one place (instead of separate .js file). After selecting any check checkboxes if I click the "edit" link then the alert keeps repeating in a loop and the no of selected checkboxes are reported as 0 1 2 3 4 5 .... in successive occurences. Anybody's help in this matter will be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
html>
<head>
<title>Cities</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
var ids = new Array();
jq(document).ready(function () {
jq("#edit").click(function(){
jq('input[name="cid"]:checked').each(function() {       
ids.push(parseInt(jq(this).val()));
}); // end checked each
if(ids.length > 0) 
alert(ids.length + " cities selected \n"+"their names: "+ids);
else
alert("Please select one or more rows to edit.");
});  // end #edit click
}); // end document ready

function setCityUpdateAction(){
jq("#edit").click();
}    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<table border=1px>
<tr><th></th>select<th>CityID</th><th>City</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cid"  value=1></td>
<td>1</td><td>London</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cid"  value=2></td>
<td>1</td><td>New York</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cid"  value=3></td>
<td>1</td><td>Paris</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td><a id="edit" href="#" onclick="setCityUpdateAction();">edit</a></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have click event handler when you write `jq("#edit").click`. So you need to get rid of onclick event handler in the `<a>` tag.
So, it should look like this:

```
<a id="edit" href="#" >edit</a>
```

Additionally, you can get rid of function as well due to click event handler already set. So remove below function.

```
setCityUpdateAction() {
       jq("#edit").click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for taking time to take note of the issue. Actually I wanted to experimented whether the jq("#edit").click() can be called from outside the jQuery $(document).ready() or not.

Comment: My experiment actually created the event-loop. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reset the ids array, Also serialize the form values,
Make sure you name every inputfield! It can be achieved with serializeArray() like this:

```
var $form = $(form).serializeArray();

$.each($form, function(i, field) {
    ... 
});
```

---

### Javascript

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

jq(document).ready(function () {
  jq("#edit").click(function(){
    var $form = jq(myform).serializeArray();
    var ids = new Array();

    jq.each($form, function(i, field) {
      ids.push(parseInt(field.value)+"-"+field.name);
    });

    if($form.length > 0) 
      alert($form.length + " cities selected \n"+"their names: "+ids);
    else
      alert("Please select one or more rows to edit.");
  });  // end #edit click
}); // end document ready
```

---

### HTML

```
<form name="myform">
<table border=1px>
<tr><th></th>select<th>CityID</th><th>City</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="london" value=1></td>
<td>1</td><td>London</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="newyork" value=2></td>
<td>2</td><td>New York</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="paris" value=3></td>
<td>3</td><td>Paris</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td><a id="edit" href="javascript:;">edit</a></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

See here how it is done: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surudoiryu/jrgzqrtb/)

Comment: Thanks SurudoiRyu. Your solution has led me to think in a different way. I shall try it.

Comment: Goodluck, dont forget to upvote or mark your solution for other people.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Cities</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function () {
jq("#edit").click(function(){
var ids = new Array();
jq('input[name="cid"]:checked').each(function() {       
ids.push(parseInt(jq(this).val()));
}); // end checked each
if(ids.length > 0) 
alert(ids.length + " cities selected \n"+"their names: "+ids);
else
alert("Please select one or more rows to edit.");
setCityUpdateAction()
});  // end #edit click
}); // end document ready

function setCityUpdateAction(){
jq("#edit").click();
}    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<table border=1px>
<tr><th></th>select<th>CityID</th><th>City</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cid"  value=1></td>
<td>1</td><td>London</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cid"  value=2></td>
<td>1</td><td>New York</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cid"  value=3></td>
<td>1</td><td>Paris</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td><a id="edit" href="#">edit</a></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

First declare the `ids` array inside the `jq("#edit").click` event, second remove the `onclick` from `a` tag and call the `setCityUpdateAction function` inside your `jq("#edit").click` event.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Sami for your response. Actually I wanted to experimented whether the jq("#edit").click() can be called from outside the jQuery $(document).ready() or not. I've kept the ids array outside  jq("#edit").click() with a view to make its data available to some other javascript function(yet to be coded) in the same html file. Could you please explain, how making ids local to  jq("#edit").click()  will improve things.

Comment: If you keep ids array outside the jq("#edit").click everytime you click edit the number of selected values will increase because your ids array is a global scop so it will keep any previous selected values, for exmple ids.length will keep increase instead of giving you just the number of values you've selected, if you want your ids array as global array scop so keep var ids = new Array(); outside jq("#edit").click()  like you've already  did and add ids = []; inseide jq("#edit").click() to reset ids array so you can get only the values you've chosen everytime you click edit.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have already taken measure for this by setting ids.length=0 at the begining of jq("#edit").click()